# CXF STS client throws Request does not contain Security header/Response message does not contain WS-Addressing properties

Tags: spring, cxf, saml, ws-security, ws-trust

working with CXF STS Service and STS client I am getting error as

```
    Jul 06, 2014 3:52:02 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.soap.MAPCodec restoreExchange WARNING: Response message does not contain WS-Addressing properties.  Not correlating response.
Jul 06, 2014 3:52:02 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor handleMessage
WARNING: Request does not contain Security header, but it's a fault.
Jul 06, 2014 3:52:03 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils retrieveMAPs
WARNING: WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
```

My configuration is as below

```
    <jaxws:client serviceClass="com.securityintegration.checkservice.servicelayer.SecurityIntegrationLayerPort" 
xmlns:tns="http://com/securityintegration/checkservice/servicelayer"
                        id="securityIntegrationClient"
                        wsdlLocation="classpath:META-INF/api/checkservice.wsdl"
                        endpointName="tns:securityIntegrationLayerServiceSOAP"
                        serviceName="tns:securityIntegrationLayerService"
        address="http://localhost:8080/CheckService/services/SecurityIntegrationService">
                <!-- KEYSTORE PROPERTIES CLIENT --> 
            <jaxws:properties>
                <entry key="ws-security.sts.client" value-ref="default.sts-client"/>
            </jaxws:properties>
            <jaxws:inInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
            </jaxws:inInterceptors>
            <jaxws:outInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
            </jaxws:outInterceptors>
        </jaxws:client>

<bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient"
            name="default.sts-client">
          <constructor-arg ref="cxf" />
          <property name="wsdlLocation" value="http://localhost:8080/StsService/services/STS?wsdl" />
          <property name="serviceName" value="{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/}SecurityTokenService" />
          <property name="endpointName" value="{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/}STS_Port" />
          <property name="properties">
              <map>
                  <entry key="ws-security.username" value="alice" />
                  <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="keystorePasswordCallback" />
                  <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value-ref="keystoreProperties" />
                  <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="${wss.stsKeystoreAlias}" />
                  </map>
          </property>
      </bean>
```

I am following the tutorial from https://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/cxf-sts-tutorial and the local STS WSDL url `http://localhost:8080/StsService/services/STS?wsdl` works fine. Please suggest some inputs

Comment: Anyone aware of this please suggest some inputs, I am really stuck here and its important

Comment: I have my example full at https://github.com/sampleref/CXFSecurity