# Request does not contain Security header, but it's a fault CXF STS Service Client error

Tags: spring, cxf, saml, ws-security, security-policy

I am getting error as provided below:

```
Jul 06, 2014 3:52:02 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.soap.MAPCodec restoreExchange WARNING: Response message does not contain WS-Addressing properties.  Not correlating response.
Jul 06, 2014 3:52:02 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor handleMessage
WARNING: Request does not contain Security header, but it's a fault.
Jul 06, 2014 3:52:03 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils retrieveMAPs
WARNING: WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
```

I have some complete example at https://github.com/sampleref/CXFSecurity  Please suggest some inputs as it is important for me. Also full details can be found at [CXF STS client throws Request does not contain Security header/Response message does not contain WS-Addressing properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595048/cxf-sts-client-throws-request-does-not-contain-security-header-response-message)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this answer for anyone else who Googles this error and arrives here.

I had the same problem with a JSF2 maven web application running on JBoss Applicatoin server, but I imagine it might happen for many other types of web apps using servlet containers for token-based security (i.e. SAML).

Simply make sure that any passwords you store in configuration files (mine was in standalone.xml) to utilise token-based security are not changed or updated, otherwise this error will occur.