# CXF STS Usernametoken symmetric binding XML Signature verification has failed

Tags: spring, cxf, ws-security, saml-2.0, ws-trust

Working with CXF STS- STS client example I followed the example at https://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/cxf-sts-tutorial and my sample code is at https://github.com/sampleref/CXFSecurity for reference. On debugging I found error as below at STS provider

```
    <<||2014-07-13 18:26:50,286||http-apr-8080-exec-3|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor:50||||>> Found UsernameToken list element 
<<||2014-07-13 18:26:50,287||http-apr-8080-exec-3|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.validate.UsernameTokenValidator:78||||>> UsernameToken user alice 
<<||2014-07-13 18:26:50,287||http-apr-8080-exec-3|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.validate.UsernameTokenValidator:79||||>> UsernameToken password type http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText 
<<||2014-07-13 18:26:50,287||http-apr-8080-exec-3|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor:115||||>> Found signature element 
<<||2014-07-13 18:26:50,288||http-apr-8080-exec-3|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor:380||||>> Verify XML Signature 
<<||2014-07-13 18:26:50,292||http-apr-8080-exec-3|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor:428||||>> XML Signature verification has failed 
<<||2014-07-13 18:26:50,292||http-apr-8080-exec-3|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor:431||||>> Signature Validation check: false
```

Please provide some inputs, Its really important working for me with this. I posted more detailed error from STS Client at
[CXF STS client throws Request does not contain Security header/Response message does not contain WS-Addressing properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595048/cxf-sts-client-throws-request-does-not-contain-security-header-response-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not supplying the password for the private key in the STS. So for example, adding the following to the StsPasswordCallbackHandler makes the decryption work:

x509Passwords.put("stskeyalias", "stskeypassword");

You also need to remove the BouncyCastle dependency from the STS pom.

Colm.

Comment: Hi Colm, Thanks for response. I have modified example at [https://github.com/sampleref/CXFSecurity] as per the suggestions, but I am still facing the same error as, `<<||2014-07-14 21:51:14,125||http-apr-8080-exec-8|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor:428||||>> XML Signature verification has failed 
<<||2014-07-14 21:51:14,127||http-apr-8080-exec-8|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor:431||||>> Signature Validation check: false 

`

Comment: I have full key generation script https://github.com/sampleref/CXFSecurity/blob/master/CheckService/src/main/resources/servicekeystore/script_genkeys.txt. I am unable to figure out what is causing this error. Can you please suggest some key areas to look that might cause this error. The log at client says `WARNING: Response message does not contain WS-Addressing properties.  Not correlating responseJul 14, 2014 10:16:43 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor handleMessage
WARNING: Request does not contain Security header, but it's a fault.`

Comment: Hi Colm, I see similar issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5679 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5724 . As it says the issue is resolved in 3.0.0 I tried to use 3.0.0. Now on startup I am getting error as `Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No DestinationFactory was found for the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http.

` Not sure of really how to proceed. Please provide some inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5679 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5724 were creating problems. I used CXF version 3.0.0 and able to get SAML assertion now

Thanks