# CXF 3.0.0 raises org.apache.cxf.BusException: No DestinationFactory was found for the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http

Tags: spring, cxf, saml, ws-security, ws-trust

Working with CXF-STS I came across exceptions as `<<||2014-07-14 21:51:14,125||http-apr-8080-exec-8|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.Signat‌​ureProcessor:428||||>> XML Signature verification has failed  <<||2014-07-14 21:51:14,127||http-apr-8080-exec-8|DEBUG|org.apache.ws.security.processor.Signat‌​ureProcessor:431||||>> Signature Validation check: false`

As discussed at post, [CXF STS Usernametoken symmetric binding XML Signature verification has failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723972/cxf-sts-usernametoken-symmetric-binding-xml-signature-verification-has-failed/24733953#24733953)
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5679
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5679
 So assuming it was fixed for version 3.0.0 I moved to it. Now on start up I am facing the error as

```
... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:176)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No DestinationFactory was found for the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.DestinationFactoryManagerImpl.getDestinationFactory(DestinationFactoryManagerImpl.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:160)
```

I am unable to figure out how can I really work with CXF STS example. Please provide some good example references to work with CXF STS in UsernameToken with Encryption Scenario

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was becuase my project was having CAMEL-CXF dependencies which contain CXF 2.7 as embedded. It might have created the conflicts with new CXF 3.0.0 version. So removing them from classpath resolved the problem

Thanks